# Usage of i18n and multi-site?

Tags: i18n-l10n, multi-sites

I beg you to make it clear for me, can i share tables in multisite installation with different databases and which ones?

If i am to use i18n on multisite, what is the best way to do that. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Sorry, of course i meant multilingual tables: locales, i18n, languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understood you almost cant use common tables on multi-site installation - i`ve been checking them one by one. First i configured all of sites - only the main site (from which tables were shared) could switch languages and translate nodes. On the others there were no switcher showing and translated nodes were not linking.

Maybe you can some, but still you got to have everything identical (starting from content types and endind with nodes)

Maybe i am wrong.